# Debug high CPU usage in Azure WebApp (Linux)

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

I have set up an Azure WebApp (Linux) to run a WordPress and an other handmade PHP app on it. All works fine but I get this weird CPU usage graph (see below).

Both apps are PHP7.0 containers.

SSHing in to the two containers and using top I see no unusual CPU hogging processes.

When I reset both apps the CPU goes back to normal and then starts to raise slowly as shown below.

The amount of HTTP requests to the apps has not relation to the CPU usage at all.

I tried to use apache2ctl to see if there are any pending requests but that seems not possible to do inside a docker container.

Anybody got an idea how to track down the cause of this?

[image: CPU usage]

This is the top output. The instance has 2 cores. Lots of idle time but still over 100% load and none of the processes use the CPU ...

[image]

Comment: What happens when you run the same container locally?

Comment: I don't have access to the actual container as it is set up by Azure automatically when you create the WebApp. I can SSH in to it but that is about all.

Comment: You do, they're all on GitHub - https://hub.docker.com/r/appsvc/

Comment: Thanks for that. 
I tried to use the 7.0 container but was never able to get it starting due to some weird "folder exists" errors. The 7.2 one did work well though and i could not see any CPU usage increasing. 
The site seems to be 7.2 compatible so I'll update the live site now and see it that solves the problem. If not at least I can no test locally.

Comment: Same problem with PHP 7.2. I replayed two weeks of requests on to the local container but that did not have the same effect.

Comment: What's `top` saying in the Azure container? CPU time being spent in kernel mode by any chance?

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: I suggest you scale up, then back down, just so you get a fresh Docker host. If you're still seeing that abnormal load open a support case.

Answer (score 0):

After handling with MS Support on that issue it seems to have boiled down to the WordPress theme being to slow or inefficient. Each request took very long and hogged CPU resources. All following requests started queuing up and thus increasing the CPU load.

Why that would not show as %CPU in top I was not explained.

They proposed to use a different theme or upscale to a multi core instance.

I am unsatisfied with that solution and will monitor further and try to find the real culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost exactly the same CPU Percentage graph as you did, although a Node.JS app instead of PHP. `Disabling Diagnostic Logs > Docker Container Logging` seems to have solved the problem for me.

[image: Docker Container Logging]

I do not need those logs because I am logging to application insights.

But, in your case you might need more of those logs. I have no solution for that, but I am guessing that heavier log rotation or reducing the sizes of the logs by other means might help